# Is there any way to support ssl while having mass virtual hosts?

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx

Is there anyway to have ssl configured for dynamic mass virtual hosts?

```
ssl_certificate ssl/$host/mysite.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key ssl/$host/mysite.com.key;
ssl_session_timeout  5m;
ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers          ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+EXP;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $host;
    root /var/www/html/$host;
}
```

Using something like this to select the right ssl cert for the host.

I have several thousand sites that need a different document roots and some need ssl capability .

Comment: this might work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319721/nginx-proxy-based-on-host-when-using-https but you would have to serve each site on another nginx instance

Comment: @isethi is there a way to do this with one nginx instance?

Comment: You have an apache config file but your asking about nginx? What does this have to do with apache?

Comment: its actualy a nginx config. but i just want to know if its possible to have dynamic ssl certs for each virtual host folder